# why is tf frame changing?

Tags: kinect, openni-camera, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo,

I am using a Kinect mounted on a PR2, ROS Electric and the openni_camera package from the openni_kinect stack.
After starting the Kinect driver with

- rgb_frame id:
  /openni_rgb_optical_frame and
- depth_frame_id:
  /openni_depth_optical_frame

the published clouds both have the frame_id /openni_rgb_optical_frame.

Has someone an explanation for me?

Thanks
David

> pr2admin@kodiak-c1:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/launch$
> roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

> ... logging to
> /u/pr2admin/.ros/log/bf52f8ea-e5a0-11e1-9e5c-001517ebc101/roslaunch-kodiak-c1-11445.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage.
> This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to
> interrupt Done checking log file disk
> usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server
> http://kodiak-c1:55334/
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS  * /rosdistro  *
> /openni_node1/use_indices  *
> /openni_node1/depth_registration  *
> /openni_node1/image_time_offset  *
> /openni_node1/depth_frame_id  *
> /openni_node1/depth_mode  *
> /openni_node1/debayering  *
> /rosversion  *
> /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
>
> - /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id  * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation  *
>   /openni_node1/depth_time_offset  *
>   /openni_node1/image_mode  *
>   /openni_node1/shift_offset  *
>   /openni_node1/device_id  *
>   /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation
>
> NODES   /
> openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
> kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
> kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
> kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
> kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>
> auto-starting new master
> process[master]: started with pid
> [11471] ROS_MASTER_URI=http://c1:11311
>
> setting /run_id to
> bf52f8ea-e5a0-11e1-9e5c-001517ebc101
> process[rosout-1]: started with pid
> [11488] started core service [/rosout]
> process[openni_node1-2]: started with
> pid [11498]
> process[kinect_base_link-3]: started
> with pid [11501]
> process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started
> with pid [11502]
> process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started
> with pid [11503]
> process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started
> with pid [11505] [ INFO]
> [1344901438.735767926]:
> [/openni_node1] Number devices
> connected: 1 [ INFO]
> [1344901438.736005847]:
> [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus
> 002:09 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from
> Microsoft (45e) with serial id
> 'A00365902376048A' [ INFO]
> [1344901438.738526435]:
> [/openni_node1] searching for device
> with index = 1 [ INFO]
> [1344901438.783217136]:
> [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI
> Camera' on bus 2:9 with serial number
> 'A00365902376048A'
> **[ INFO] [1344901438.798280799]: rgb_frame_id =
> '/openni_rgb_optical_frame'  [ INFO]
> [1344901438.800312236]: depth_frame_id
> = '/openni_depth_optical_frame'**

===

> **pr2admin@kodiak-c1:~$ rostopic echo /camera/depth/points | grep frame  
> > frame_id: /openni_rgb_optical_frame**
> >
> > **pr2admin@kodiak-c1:~$ rostopic echo /camera/rgb/image_color | grep frame
> frame_id: /openni_rgb_optical_frame**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41299/why-is-tf-frame-changing?/) by [DavidF](https://answers.ros.org/users/3026/davidf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi DavidF!

That is an easy one!! If you look into the file *$(find openni_camera)/launch/openni_node.launch* you will see that the parameter *depth_registration* is set to true:

```
<param name="depth_registration" value="true" />
```

This means that the depth image is being registered with the rgb image (so the pixels in both images represent the exact same points in the real world) and therefore both */camera/rgb/image_color* and */camera/depth/points* are now expressed in terms of */openni_rgb_optical_frame*.

If you set that parameter to false, then */camera/depth/points* will have frame_id = */openni_depth_optical_frame* as you would expect.

I hope this was helpful.
Martin.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2